# How to create multiple custom labels?

Tags: metadata, customlabel, force.com-ide

I need to create many custom labels at once. These are all for the same VF page, and I'm grouping them in a category. However, creating many in the web interface is just too repetitive and slow.

I've created a Force.com IDE (Eclipse) project to edit the CustomLabels.xml but I'm getting an error when saving the file.

Save error: Conflict found while preparing to save 'CustomLabels.labels' to server.  Remote instance has been updated since last save or sync.  Use the Synchronize Perspective to resolve the conflict.

When I sync I see that the CustomLabels file is blank. Just the outer tags are there. So I go to the web interface but the previously created labels are already there. So I refresh entire project from server, I see my changes discarded but the file went back to the expected state. I mean, with the previously created labels there. So I try to edit once again with just one more label, checking it has everything right and save again. And I get the same error. And the sync view shows the file blank again.

I'm also checking cloud9 IDE but have not found nothing for custom labels there.

The real problem is: How to add custom labels in a faster, more convenient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your project is configured correctly. Go to src/package.xml, and verify that the following code is somewhere in there:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomLabels</name>
</types>
```

Next, force a save to the server by right-clicking the CustomLabels.labels file, and choosing Force.com / Save to server. You'll get a dialog confirming the save, choose Yes, and then the file should save correctly.

The synchronization code does behave a bit oddly sometimes, but by forcing a save, you can usually get the deployment to work correctly.

Comment: Had to force the save, as if I was working offline. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I use SublimeText. With that editor, changing the CustomLabels.Labels file is just like changing any other file and works as you are expecting Eclipse to work.

Copy-Paste, mass edits and any other rich-editor tool all work just fine.